# Redistributable .net framework installer

Tags: c#, .net, installation, redistributable

Is there a redistributable web installer for .net framework 4.0? Preferably, it'd detect the correct language version to install and download it from the internet.

I want to bundle this web installer with my 4.0 application, so that the download size of setup package is as small as possible (40MB of full offline installer could scare users), plus I don't want to deal with detecting the necessary version (x86, x64, which language) to install.

EDIT:
As to how I create the setup. I'll go for the easiest option. My application is really trivial. I just need to copy some files and make shortcuts in Start Menu / Desktop. 
What's the simplest/fastest solution to this? The setup project that can be build with VS (I'm using VS 2010).

Comment: how are you creating the setup project? I think you can set some properties like download the .NET framework at setup time if not present... check this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733

Comment: You have two choices you can embed the installer within your setup or have your setup download it.  Wouldn't it be fair easier to just tell people to go download it?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17113

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't want to risk lower conversion rates because of user's laziness / inability to download the correct thing. I'm looking for a solution that's most convienient to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your setup project you should embed the .Net 4 Framework. But instead of adding the full offline version you simply download and embed [this web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17851). It checks the currently running machine and downloads only the necessary files. So everyone who already has the .Net framework installed just gets 870kb of death data with your setup (thats the size of the web installer) and anybody else downloads as much as needed for the current machine.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio setup project covers your needs.

check this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx

**edit** fixed the link, you might want to check the *web bootstrapper* and *redistribute framework* related sections

Comment: Setup projects are not supported any more- since VS2012. However the link to ".NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers" is useful.